# calling WCF method asynchronously

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I'm looking for feedback on the following code. I've read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) that I should avoid use of async void.

So as a result I've implemented the following in a method..

```
foreach (var sample in returns)
{
    _logger.Debug("Calling async method");
    var resultFromMethodCall = CallMethodAsync(uploadReturn);
    _logger.Debug("Continuing....");

}




async Task<Tuple<bool,long>> CallMethodAsync(Sample sampleReturn)
{
    try
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Tuple<bool, long> results = await client.ValidateSampleReturnAsync(sampleReturn);
        _logger.Debug("call to Sample Return validator completed for sample: {0}", results.Item2);
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Error occured while calling WCF service");
        return new Tuple<bool, long>(false, sampleReturn.Id);
    }
}
```

When I do nothing with the returned variable resultFromMethodCall, the logging indicates the all is working as I expect. However when I log out items from the variable resultFromMethodCall, it appears that its now running synchronously as it waits for the object to be returned from the call.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or am I completely misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: The calling site will start waiting on the task's result when you start using the result of the task. Anything in between the calling of the async method and the usage of the async method's result will run without waiting for the task's result.

Comment: Aren't you missing an await in your calling code?

Comment: Is it ok that I do nothing with the result of the task? Also the await is in the async method that is called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallMethodAsync` is correct.

If you don't await (or Wait) `resultFromMethodCall` execution will continue while that task is still running. Whether you should allow that depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks usr. I've a db full of records that need to be validated. The 'returns' is a list of records that need to be validated. CallMethodAsync calls a WCF service that validates each record. The WCF service updates the db with the validation result. I don't really care about the validation result. so in theory I'd just use the void but I've read that's not the intended use of async void..

Comment: I think what you really want is to process a big list of items with a certain amount of parallelism. This is a standard problem. The easiest way to do that is `Parallel.ForEach` in combination with synchronous calls. There's an async version as well but you would likely not derive any benefits from it.

Comment: So if I use Parallel.ForEach, would I call the WCF service synchronous operation as opposed to the asynchronous operation? aka replace the foreach loop above with a Parallel.ForEach? (thank you for your help!)

Comment: Yeah, you need to be synchronous because there is no async parallel loop built in to the framework. Async loop code is available on the web but it accomplishes nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

> However when I log out items from the variable resultFromMethodCall it appears that its now running synchronously as it waits for the object to be returned from the call.

If you're using `resultFromMethodCall.Result` to get the items, then yes, it's blocking and running synchronously.

If you're using `await resultFromMethodCall` to get the items, then no, it's not running synchronously. However, it is running *sequentially* - meaning that the method will "pause" at the `await` and only continue when the `resultFromMethodCall` task completes.

Comment: Good psychic debugging. He's probably calling `Result` in code not shown.

Comment: Yes... in code not shown (another version of it as I wanted to see what happened if I logged out the items in resultFromMethodCall.Result.) Sorry I should have been cleared and posted both versions